# Create a pandas df column from last value in another column for which a third column is 1

Tags: pandas

Say, I have a DataFrame like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df =  pd.DataFrame({'data' : np.arange(10), 'trigger' : np.random.randint(0,2, size=10)})
```

I'd like to get a third column which contains in row i that value of column 'data' with the greatest index smaller than i for which 'trigger' is 1.

A naïve implementation would be this:

```
lastdata = df.iloc[0]['data']
wanted = []
for _,row in df.iterrows():
    if row['trigger']:
        lastdata = row['data']
    wanted.append(lastdata)
df['wanted'] = wanted
```

Is there any other (efficient) way to get this without iterating through the data frame?

Comment: Your code does not run, it raises an error can you post what your desired df looks like, thanks

Comment: Sorry, copied the wrong line from my REPL.

Comment: Could you give an example what you need. It's difficult to understand the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here you go:

```
df['wanted'] = pd.Series(df.index*df['trigger']).cummax().apply( lambda i:df.loc[i,'data'])
```

First rows use data[0] before first trigger occurs.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know `cummax()`!  Thanks.  Why the `apply()` and `lambda()`, though?  `df['wanted'] = (df['trigger']*df['data']).cummax()` seems to work.